# What would be suggested books for beginners to Zeeman Effect and Quantum Physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, resource-recommendations

I have great interest for learning what Quantum Mechanics governs and the Zeeman Effect; however, I have no idea where to start.

I believe that the best books are recommended by fellow academics who have studied or mastered the subjects, so I direct my question at you: What would you recommend for a physics student and enthusiast who is interested in Albert Einstein's and Hendrik Lorentz's works?

- I have not read into their works in detail, but only have an idea of what they have accomplished
- I do not know their terminologies (yet)
- However, I'd prefer detailed technical academic publications rather than dumbed down language (we can always look the terms up)

It would be my preference to be recommended a thick text book used in lectures that covers AND focuses in these two subjects; but, as experienced scholars in these subjects I would welcome the direction you recommend to go.

Any recommendations for books written by Hendrix or Einstein would be appreciated as well.

Comment: @david-z if I read on quantum mechanics on the books recommended on the duplicated question, would I also learn about the Zeeman effect?

Comment: Yes, that's one of the topics covered by pretty much any introductory quantum mechanics course (or book).